# Changing the background color of an NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa

Is it a chance to programatically change the background color of NSCollectionView?

I was trying subclassing.. but not working..

```
 @interface CollectionViewBg : NSCollectionView
```

in .m

```
 [self setBackgroundColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSColor blueColor], nil]];
```

Comment: Worked for me (clean test project with unconfigured NSCollectionView). Make sure that your collection view's prototype view is not opaquely filled. Also make sure you actually set "CollectionViewBg" as the view's class in IB.

Comment: Also, you can use `arrayWithObject:` to create a one-element array.

Comment: What method are you sending `setBackgroundColors:` from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .m, remove this line :

```
 [self setBackgroundColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSColor blueColor], nil]];
```

And use this code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{

[[NSColor blueColor] setFill];
NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

}
```

*Also don't forget to change class of NSCollectionView object in IB to CollectionViewBg.*

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I assume you don't want any of the collected items to be drawn? And is there a reason why you suggest avoiding NSCollectionView's `backgroundColors` property?

Comment: Hmm.. something wrong with my edited CollectionView.. I created a new project and yes.. it works like a charm.. So thanks everyone for help!!! I will go testing what I have done bad in my code :)

Comment: It doesn't have the effect I would expect. @Peter Hosey NSRectFill() does work here. It *seems* to draw where the backgroundColors do not. Neither approach gives a clear transparent background to the view below.

Answer (score 0):

Guess subclassing isn't a great idea, because most of Cocoa controls provide various techniques to avoid subclassing in order to customize appearance and behavior.

In this particular case, you can set `backgroundView` property to your `NSCollectionView` and provide a custom view that is dedicated for drawing  a custom background.

If you need to change only background color, then you can consider take advantage of the fact that collection view usually resists inside scroll view. Just set `backgroundColor` and `drawsBackground` properties of `NSScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more modern solution. First, make yourself an NSView subclass that draws the effect you want to achieve. Here's a simple one that paints a block colour:

```
class ColouredView: NSView {
    @IBInspectable var color: NSColor = .windowBackgroundColor

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        color.setFill()
        dirtyRect.fill()
    }
}
```

Now go to your nib or storyboard and drag a custom view onto the left bar. We don't want it to be part of the view hierarchy, but we do want it to be listed under the view controller containing the collection view. Just drag it in below 'First Responder'. You can then set up any important properties or relationships - in my case, the background colour.

Finally, right-click your collection view and connect its 'background view' outlet to your custom view. This lets you do all the setup in your storyboard. If you like you can make your custom view `@IBDesignable` but I find that usually causes more trouble than it's worth.